# ImageView - align left - scale height - crop width, does noone know?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to get an image inside a ImageView to scale to fill the height, keep being aligned to the left side, and crop of the width accordingly to keep the width/height ratio.

Scaletype - centercrop kinda does this, but aligns the image center (As the name says), but I want the image aligned to the left, so I do not get anything cropped of the left side of the image.

Here is my currenct layout:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:background="#000000"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/lineLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="93dp">
    <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:src="@drawable/top"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: may be scaleType `FIT_START`?

Comment: Problem with FIT_START is that you can not set it to scale to height over width. When I use FIT_START the width fits, but then it does not scale to fill the height of the ImageView.

Comment: I have messed around with all the scaletypes. I have messed around with the layout with the combos I could come up with like android:layout_alignParentLeft, with out any luck. I hoped someone could tell me how this is done, I am surprised that it is so difficult to do somthing so simple :-/